# Save Outlook attachment to memory instead of disk

Tags: python, excel, outlook, io

I have a couple hundred daily Excel attachments in email that I want to pull appropriate data from and save into a database. I want to avoid saving each attachment to disk only to re-open from disk to read, since I'll never need the files saved to disk ever again. For this project, sure, I could just do it and delete them, but there ought to be a better way.

Here's what I'm doing so far

```py
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders[blah].Folders[blahblah]

for item in folder.items:
    for att in item.Attachments:
        att.SaveAsFile(???) # This is where I need something cool, like stream or bytes or something that I don't understand
        # do something with the file, either read with pandas or openpyxl
```

If I can get around even doing the save and have `pandas` / `openpyxl` read it without saving, that would be great, but neither of them can read the `att` directly.

Comment: Use [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o).

Comment: goto definition of `att` and see if there are other properties/methods related to stream.

Comment: @LeiYang, from what I understand, the python object is just pulling from the Windows ComObject (when I do `att` I get <COMObject <unknown>> and the in-python help/dir info is minimal. This Windows link has info on properties and methods, and don't seem to have something that will work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment

Comment: @MattDMo, that's what I was thinking, but I don't quite understand it. For example, I can't do `att.SaveAsFile(io.BytesIO)`, that gives a "File name or directory name is not valid". It sort of makes sense to me how I would use `io.BytesIO` with an object that I have in my python process, but in this case I don't really have the object yet.

Comment: You need to instantiate an `io.BytesIO` object first - `obj = io.BytesIO(); att.SaveAsFile(obj)`. You can then pass `obj` to other processes as needed, such as the `pd.read_excel()` dataframe constructor.

Comment: in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/attachments/modify-an-attachment-of-an-outlook-email-message)  i found some C# statement `var attachmentData =
                    attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
                    PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN); //Retrieve the attachment as an array of bytes` which might find equivalent in python.

Comment: @MattDMo, getting the same error for that. I did `f = io.BytesIO(); att.SaveAsFile(f)` and got the same "Cannot save the attachment. File name or directory name is not valid."

Comment: Then you're probably running up against some peculiarity in Windows where `SaveAsFile()` actually requires a valid Windows file name. I'd suggest trying to track down Lei Yang's suggestion, that sounds more promising.

Comment: @LeiYang - `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN)` will fail for large (>64k or so) files, especially in the online (no cache) mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook Object Model won't let you do that: `Attachment`.[SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) only allows to specify a valid file name.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only), the one and only way to access attachment data (Extended MAPI does not know anything about files) is to open the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` MAPI property as `IStream` interface: `IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN, IID_IStream, ...)`. You can then retreive the data directly from the `IStream` interface.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDOAttachment](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`AsStream` / `AsArray` / `AsText` properties that allow to access raw attachment data without saving it as file first.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I appreciate this. Not sure if using Redemption will be an option, and for this particular task I think I will just need to bite the bullet and save them all to task and delete them afterward. Glad to know there wasn't something trivial and obvious I was missing...

Comment: For what it is worth, performance hit due to creating/reading/deleting the temporary files is negligible (<5% in my tests, could not measure it any better).

Comment: In most cases I had to deal with, the primary concern was the possibility of leaving the file on a permanent storage, only if for a brief period of time.